# Format jqPlot pointLabels to currency

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I am trying to get the commas in my values.

so far I can get the $, but nothing else:

```
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true, formatString: '$%s' },
                },
```

Is there a way to get a pointLabel to look like **$45,666,444** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the last value in the data ponit array in the data series is used
   for the label.  For most series renderers, extra data can be added to the 
   data point arrays and the last value will be used as the label.

For instance, 
   this series:

```
   [[1,4], [3,5], [7,2]]
```

Would, by default, use the y values in the labels.
   Extra data can be added to the series like so:

```
   [[1,4,'mid'], [3 5,'hi'], [7,2,'low']]
```

And now the point labels would be 'mid', 'low', and 'hi'.

Options to the point labels and a custom labels array can be passed into the
   "pointLabels" option on the series option like so:

```
   series:[{pointLabels:{
      labels:['mid', 'hi', 'low'],
      location:'se',
      ypadding: 12
      }
   }]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tickOptions:{
   formatString: "%'.2f"
},
```

Comment: To get the '$' in, I've found you can just add one. So, `formatString: "$%'.2f"`.